# How to getElementById in Google Apps Script from external Html file?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm trying to plug my Html form to Google Apps Script to automate an email notification but also include form inputs in the email body. Example: I have a form on my website with a "name" and "email" input. A visitor goes on my site and fills out the form. When the visitor clicks on the "submit" button, whatever is filled in the inputs is stored and sent to Google Apps Script. A function is then run on Google Apps Script that sends me an email. The email's body has the "name" and "email" input data. That's the dream, here's reality!:

**Code.gs (Google Apps Script):**

```js
//EMAIL NOTIFICATION
function sendNotification(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
  var recipients = "myemail@gmail.com";
  var message = '';
  function createSpreadsheetChangeTrigger() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
  }  
  var subject = 'Client Lead Notification';
  var body = 'You have a new client submission on your Google Sheets spreadsheet' + ss.getUrl();
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
};
```

**Html (external):**

```html
<input id="inputTest" >

<button onclick="storeInputData()">Send</button>

<script>
    function storeInputData()
    {
        var inputData = document.getElementById("inputTest").value;
        document.write("This is " + inputData);
    }
</script>
```

My question is, how do I getElementById in Google Apps Script the same way it's done in the Html (storeInputData)?

Comment: *how do I getElementById in Google Apps Script the same way it's done in the Html (storeInputData)?* why? *That's the dream* Look into apps script documentation about doPost and web app

Comment: The answer is simple,  Google Script doesn't have a getElementById() method.  Google Apps Script runs on a server not clientside.

Comment: Are you trying to get the name and email from the form submission?

Answer (score 0):

### You need to embed your HTML form into a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Apps Script Web Apps feature methods that allow communication between the client-side HTML / Javascript files and the server-side Apps Script file.

Of particular interest for you would be [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myfunction...-any-server-side-function) that allow you to pass HTML element values to an Apps Script function, sample:

> index.html

```
...
<input id="inputTest" >

<button onclick="storeInputData()">Send</button>

<script>
    function storeInputData()
    {
        var inputData = document.getElementById("inputTest").value;
        google.script.run.passInputData(inputData);
    }
</script>
...
```

> Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function passInputData(value) {
  Logger.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still a beginner with Google Apps Script. My goal though, is to pass my HTML element to Google Script locally - meaning from a website or from an html file on my hard drive, not directly through a web app. "google.script.run" only works if I'm putting the html file in the web app. So my local html input goes -> to Google Script and -> Google Script stores that input in a var for later use.

Comment: You can incoporate the Web App with its URL into your already existing html file.